# How to identify dummy data in pandas and delete?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to identify the dummy data in a dataframe and delete them? In my data below, there are random characters in each column that I need to delete.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Name' : ['Tom', 'AABBCC', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'XXXX', 'John', 'U'],
        'Address1': ['High Street', 'uwdfjfuf', '00000', 'Green Lane', 'Kingsway', 'Church Street', 'iwefwfn'],
        'Address2': ['Park Avenue', 'The Crescent', 'ABCXYZ', 'Highfield Road', 'Stanley Road', 'New Street', '1ca2s597']}

contact_details = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Code to identify and delete dummy data



print(contact_details)
```

Output of the above code:

```
     Name       Address1        Address2
0     Tom    High Street     Park Avenue
1  AABBCC       uwdfjfuf    The Crescent
2  Joseph          00000          ABCXYZ
3   Krish     Green Lane  Highfield Road
4    XXXX       Kingsway    Stanley Road
5    John  Church Street      New Street
6       U        iwefwfn        1ca2s597
```

Comment: What is the criteria for random characters ?

Comment: @Psidom, the data which are not a word or name

Answer (score 0):

have you investigated your data? Are always the "good data" a combination of lowercase and uppercase characters? If so you could make a function to find those dummy data, for example:

```
if text.lower() == text or text.upper() == text:
    # text is dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a good definition of good and bad values for each column, there's really nothing you can do automatically. There are a couple of data cleaning tricks you can use to make those values easier to find in a large dataset.

Starting with your original dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'AABBCC', 'Joseph', 'Krish', 'XXXX', 'John', 'U'],
        'Address1': ['High Street', 'uwdfjfuf', '00000', 'Green Lane', 'Kingsway', 'Church Street', 'iwefwfn'],
        'Address2': ['Park Avenue', 'The Crescent', 'ABCXYZ', 'Highfield Road', 'Stanley Road', 'New Street', '1ca2s597']}
contact_details = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The first thing you can do is get the unique values for a column to reduce the number of values you're looking through.

```
# get all the unique values in the 'Name' column
names = contact_details['Name'].unique()
```

Next you can sort them so that any near-duplicates will stand out more easily. Near duplicates happen often with errors in data entry.

```
# sort them alphabetically and then take a closer look
names.sort()
print(list(names))
```

So for example, is you had seen the values `' Tom'`, `'Tom'`, and `'Tom '`, you know you need to strip whitespace from names.

```
contact_details['Name'] = contact_details['Name'].strip()
```

Another benefit of sorting unique values in a column is that string values that start with a number will all be at the beginning of the list, and lowercase strings will be sorted at the end. This makes a couple of your `'Address1` values stand out.

```
# get all the unique values in the 'Address1' column
address1 = contact_details['Address1'].unique()
address1.sort()
print(list(address1))
```

This gives me the list of unique values:

```
['00000', 'Church Street', 'Green Lane', 'High Street', 'Kingsway', 'iwefwfn', 'uwdfjfuf']
```

It's not clear yet if the first value is valid, but those last two look suspect. If I want to remove those, I can filter them out by selecting all rows where `Address1` is **not** in a list of bad values.

```
contact_details_filtered = contact_details[~contact_details['Address1'].isin(['iwefwfn', 'uwdfjfuf'])]
print(contact_details_filtered)
```

This gives me the output:

```
     Name       Address1        Address2
0     Tom    High Street     Park Avenue
2  Joseph          00000          ABCXYZ
3   Krish     Green Lane  Highfield Road
4    XXXX       Kingsway    Stanley Road
5    John  Church Street      New Street
```

Row 2 is definitely suspect, and row 4 is questionable, but I think you get the idea of how to find and remove values that look like placeholders or just bad data.

Comment: I see. Thank you!